# WPF ListBox can not set BackgroundColor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a problem, that I can not set the background color of my ListBox-Control. I create a ItemsControl template and DataTemplates:

```
 <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="LogViewerStyle">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>      
  </Setter>   

 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogEntry}">
  <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Index" Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Date" Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="2,0,2,0" Foreground="{Binding Path=LineNumbersColor, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}" Cursor="RightArrow.cur" TextAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="{Binding Path=WordWrapping, ElementName=LogViewerProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToTextWrap}}" />

  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I try to give my ListBox a BackgroundColor nothing happens:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="LogViewer" Background="Cornsilk" Style="{StaticResource LogViewerStyle}">
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding Path=WordWrapping, ElementName=LogViewerProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToScrollbarVisibility}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding Path=VerticalScrollbarVisible, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}">
        <ItemsPresenter/>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Template>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True">
      </VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

At the moment I don't have clue why. Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply a style to ListBox with the key LogViewerStyle which futhermore defines a template but then you create another template for ListBox implicitly.

Why? That is not wpf's usual bread. Its not making sence, is it?

Remove one of them please.

Though to answer your question you will have to tell your ScrollViewer to listen to the Background of the ListBox.

Take a look at this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="MyListBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
          <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>      
  </Setter>
```

And then just set the style on the ListBox.

```
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource MyListBox}" />
```

Take a look how it tells Grid to have its Background same as ListBox will have.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" applies background for me

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="100" x:Name="LogViewer" Background="Red" Style="{StaticResource LogViewerStyle}">
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding Path=WordWrapping, ElementName=LogViewerProperty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToScrollbarVisibility}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding Path=VerticalScrollbarVisible, ElementName=LogViewerProperty}">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True">
                            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
```